# Selecting one specific data row (required), and 3 others (specific data row must be included)

Tags: postgresql

I need to select a specific row and 2 other rows that is not that specific row (a total of 3). The specific row must always be included in the 3 results. How should I go about it? I think it can be done with a UNION ALL, but do I have another choice? Thanks all! :)

Here are my scripts to create the sample tables:

```
create table users (
    user_id serial primary key,
    user_name varchar(20) not null
);

create table result_table1 (
    result_id serial primary key,
    user_id int4 references users(user_id),
    result_1 int4 not null
);

create table result_table2 (
    result_id serial primary key,
    user_id int4 references users(user_id),
    result_2 int4 not null
);

insert into users (user_name) values ('Kevin'),('John'),('Batman'),('Someguy');
insert into result_table1 (user_id, result_1) values (1, 20),(2, 40),(3, 70),(4, 42);
insert into result_table2 (user_id, result_2) values (1, 4),(2, 3),(3, 7),(4, 5);
```

Here is my UNION query:

```
SELECT  result_table1.user_id,
        result_1,
        result_2

FROM    result_table1

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT  user_id

    FROM    users
) users 
ON users.user_id = result_table1.user_id

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT  result_table2.user_id,
            result_2

    FROM    result_table2
) result_table2 
ON result_table2.user_id = result_table1.user_id

WHERE   users.user_id = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT  result_table1.user_id,
        result_1,
        result_2

FROM    result_table1

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT  user_id

    FROM    users
) users 
ON users.user_id = result_table1.user_id

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT  result_table2.user_id,
            result_2

    FROM    result_table2
) result_table2 
ON result_table2.user_id = result_table1.user_id

WHERE   users.user_id != 1

LIMIT 3;
```

Are there any options other than a UNION? The query works and does what I want for now, but will it always include user_id = 1 if I had a larger set of rows (assume that user_id = 1 will always be there)? :(

Thank you all! :)

Comment: Can you maybe post an example `DataFrame`, show what results you want to end up with, and maybe some of the things you have tried?

Comment: I think `union all` is your best choice.

Comment: The important part is how many rows you want if the specific row doesn't exists.

Comment: It depends. Your question does not have enough information. Start with your Postgres version and table definition and show your query.

Comment: You have limitless choices. We can tell you what they are if you post your SQL. Or at least explain what your query is trying to do.